# LINQ method chaining and granular error handling

Tags: c#, linq, chaining, method-chaining

I have a method which can be written pretty neatly through method chaining:

```
return viewer.ServerReport.GetParameters()
    .Single(p => p.Name == Convention.Ssrs.RegionParamName)
    .ValidValues
    .Select(v => v.Value);
```

However I'd like to be able to do some checks at each point as I wish to provide helpful diagnostics information if any of the chained methods returns unexpected results.

To achieve this, I need to break up all my chaining and follow each call with an `if` block. It makes the code a lot less readable.

Ideally I'd like to be able to weave in some chained method calls which would allow me to handle unexpected outcomes at each point (e.g. throw a meaningful exception such as `new ConventionException("The report contains no parameter")` if the first method returns an empty collection). Can anyone suggest a simple way to achieve such a thing?

**Edit:**

This is the result of using @JeffreyZhao's answer:

```
return viewer.ServerReport.GetParameters()
    .Assert(result => result.Any(), "The report contains no parameter")
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == Convention.Ssrs.RegionParamName)
    .Assert(result => result != null, "The report does not contain a region parameter")
    .ValidValues
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .Assert(result => result.Any(), "The region parameter in the report does not contain any valid value");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can use this approach.

```
static T Check<T>(this T value)
{
    if (...) throw ...;

    return value;
}
```

then:

```
xxx.Single(...).Check().Select(...).Check()...
```

**Update:**

You can even:

```
static T Validate<T>(this T value, Func<T, bool> validate, string errorMessage)
{
    if (!validate(value)) 
        throw new ValidationFailedException(errorMessage);

    return value;
}
```

then:

```
xxxx.Single()
    .Validate(v => v > 0, "Must be greater than zero")
    .NextStep()
    .Validate(...);
```

Comment: This looks good. And given the nature of error checking I suspect it may be that generic methods won't be needed (ie often the nature of the error check is specific to a given type). The general approach of having an extension method that just returns the input unmodified though is exactly what is needed.

Comment: You're right. I've added a more general `Validate` method and in that case the generic is required.

Comment: Nice. I wish I could +1 it again for that nice little `Validate` function. :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks @JeffreyZhao! I took your method and just renamed it to Assert. I'm now thinking that the ideal solution would be to add overloads to the existing LINQ methods, as this would allow me to use the input in my exception (as really, what holds useful information for diagnostics is the input to these methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily split the process in separate steps with local variables:

```
var result1 = viewer.ServerReport.GetParameters();
var result2 = result1.Single(p => p.Name == Convention.Ssrs.RegionParamName);
var result3 = result2.ValidValues;
var result4 = result3.Select(v => v.Value);
return result4;
```

Now you can do any checks you want between the steps.

Note however that some results doesn't actually do any work. The last step for example doesn't produce a list as result, it produces an enumerable that reads from `ValidValues`, so any errors in that step would happen when you use the result, not inside this method. You might want to add `.ToList()` at the end of some steps to realise the result.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using of [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) (e.g. add post-condition to `ServerReport.GetParameters` to ensure that methods doesn't return empty collection). They allow to do what you want in more elegant way, than writing your own checking logic.

```
class ReportParameter { }
class ServerReport
{
    public ReportParameter[] GetParameters()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ReportParameter[]>() != null && Contract.Result<ReportParameter[]>().Length > 0,
            Resource1.Oops);

        // here's some logic to build parameters array...
        return new ReportParameter[0];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Oops! I need at least one parameter!
var parameters = new ServerReport().GetParameters();
```

Comment: That sounds ideal. In my particular case though, it's the data that needs to conform to certain expectations, so static analysis couldn't help (I realize this also provides runtime checks, though, but not sure taking this new approach and using new tools is warranted in my case given this). Would I be able to inject my own logic when a condition isn't satisfied? I really need to look more into this!

Comment: I mean logic that would allow me to provide a helpful, specific exception rather than a generic exception type, thus making it easier for my calling code to handle recoverable errors.

Comment: @Clafou, what king of logic do you want to inject? Contract violation brings to an `ContractException`. You can handle it.

Comment: Sounds good! There could be other requirements that would require injecting logic, such as doing some special logging should a certain condition not be met. That's beyond what I asked for though!

Comment: @Clafou, I've added tiny sample to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Dennis! In the case I have, ServerReport and its associated types that I'm querying are part of a 3rd party library (Microsoft ReportViewer) hence I guess I can't extend it with code contracts. And the contract in my particular application is really at the data level (ServerReport is merely the component I use to read this data--the constraints that apply to my application aren't constraints for ServerReport in general).